# Unit-testing a functional core of value objects: how to verify contracts without mocking?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, value-type, value-objects

I wanted to give the [Functional Core/Imperative Shell](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/boundaries) approach a shot, especially since Swift's `struct`s are so easy to create.

Now they drive me nuts in unit tests.

**How do you unit test a net of value objects?**

---

Maybe I'm too stupid to search for the right terms, but in the end, the more unit tests I write, the more I think I should delete all the old ones. In other words my tests seem to bubble up the call chain as long as I don't provide mock objects. Which is impossible for (`struct`) value objects, because there's no way to replace them with a fake double unless I introduce a protocol, which doesn't work well in production code when methods return `Self` or have associated types.

Here's a very simple example:

```
struct Foo {
    func obtainBar() -> Bar? { 
      // ... 
    }
}

struct FooManager {
    let foos: [Foo]

    func obtainFirstBar() -> Bar {
        // try to get a `Bar` from every `Foo` in `foos`; pass the first
        // one which isn't nil down
    }
}
```

This works well with a concrete `Foo` class or struct. Now how am I supposed to test what `obtainFirstBar()` does? -- I plug in one and two and zero `Foo` instances and see what happens.

But then I'm replicating my knowledge and assertions about `Foo`'s `obtainBar()`. Well, either I move the few `FooTests` into `FooManagerTests`, which sounds stupid, or I use mocks to verify the incoming call instead of merely asserting a certain return value. But you can't subclass a `struct`, so you create a protocol:

```
protocol FooType {
    func obtainBar() -> Bar
}

struct Foo: FooType { /* ... */ }

class TestFoo: FooType { /* do some mocking/stubbing */}
```

When `Bar` is complex enough to warrant its own unit tests and it seems it should be mocked, you end up with this instead:

```
protocol FooType {
    typealias B: BarType

    func obtainBar() -> B
}
```

But then the compiler will complain that `FooManager`'s collection of `foos` doesn't work this way. Thanks, generics.

```
struct FooManager<F: FooType where F.B == Bar> {
    let foos: [F]         // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ added for clarity 

    func obtainFirstBar() -> Bar { /* ... */ }
}
```

You can't pass in different kinds of `Foo`, though. Only one concrete `FooType` is allowed, no weird mixes of `BlueFoo` and `RedFoo`, even if both return the same `Bar` and seem to realize the `FooType` protocol in the same way. This isn't Objective-C and duck typing isn't possible. Protocols don't seem to add much benefit in terms of abstraction here anyway *unless they're not depending on anything else which is a protocol or Self.*

If protocols lead to confusion and not much benefit at all, I'd rather stop using them. But how do I write unit tests if one object is mostly a convoluted net of dependent objects, all being value types, seldomly optional, without moving all tests for every permutation in the test suite of the root object(s)?